# Trying to get the commits in bitbucket using fetch api

Tags: javascript, node.js, bitbucket, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch the commits from bitbucket using fetch. I end up with below error.

```
{
  errors: [
    {
      context: null,
      message: 'You are not permitted to access this resource',
      exceptionName: 'com.atlassian.bitbucket.AuthorisationException'
    }
  ]
}
```

CODE:

```
let base64 = require('base-64');

let url = 'https://example.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/CD/repos/central-msp-gitops/commits';
let username = 'example';
let password = 'password';

let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'text/json');
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic' + base64.encode(username + ":" + password));

const fetchh = async () =>{
    await fetch(url, {method:'GET',
        headers: headers,
       })
       .then(response => response.json())
.then(json => console.log(json));
} 

fetchh()
```

Please help , I have referred many docs but couldn't sort it out. What am I missing ?

When I curl it from my terminal it produces the expected output, so the creds are fine.

Help!!!

Comment: **Just a TYPO**; missing a space after `Basic`

Comment: I'd recommend using template literals, makes it easier to spot concatenation problems... `\`Basic ${base64.encode(\`${username}:${password}\`)}\``